# Can loop cuts be snapped to anything other than increments?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, snapping

I'm trying to make a loop cut slide along a face and snap to a vertex.

However, even though I have "snap to vertex" mode enabled, the loop cut slides on the face only in increments.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug, or must I first place a loop cut, then G to grab it and drag it to snap to the vertex?

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible atm, only transform operators (translate, rotate, scale) seem to use snapping settings. You'll notice that the loop cut and slide operator makes a loop cut, then runs the edge slide operator. The snapping you see when holding `ctrl` or `shift+ctrl` is only constraining the *relative offset* of the edge slide operator to nice round numbers. As you said, I think the only way atm is to snap with a transform operator..